# erratic simulator gazebo does not work anymore

Tags: ros, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried erratic simulation some months ago and it worked, but now it does not work anymore. If I launch "roslaunch erratic_description erratic_empty_world.launch", gazebo gui starts without the robot and it seems blocked on:

> waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model

The gzserver process consumes a lot of CPU (100%), but I do not know if it is related.
I tried also on another computer with the same results.
I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and fuerte.
Does someone have an advice to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Update. I did another test. The *erratic_empty_world.launch* file is:

```
<launch>
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

<node name="empty_world_server"
      pkg="gazebo"
      type="gazebo"
      args="-u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/empty.world"
      respawn="false"
      output="screen"/>

<node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

<include file="$(find erratic_description)/launch/erratic_mobile_base.launch" />
```

I tried to run each node separately with 4 commands: *roscore*, *rosrun gazebo gazebo empty.world*, *rosrun gazebo gui*, *roslaunch erratic_description erratic_mobile_base.launch*.
and it worked. The general *erratic_empty_world.launch* file should do the same, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45883/erratic-simulator-gazebo-does-not-work-anymore/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just change the node name from node "empty_world_server" to "gazebo" and it should be able to find the /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model service and the rest of them.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2012-10-15**:
Thanks now it works!! But why some months ago did it work? Is it changed? I thought that "name" was a customizable field.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like you try it on fuerte (and used it on electric the last time you tried). The Gazebo server (simulation) and client (visualization) have been split into two independent processes starting with fuerte, which means that old launch files might start up without a Gazebo GUI.
Start the launch file and type

```
rosrun gazebo gui
```

afterwards. The Gazebo GUI should come up then.

/edit: As mentioned below in the comments, the above wasn't the solution. Just tried it myself, and the robot indeed doesn't spawn with the spawner waiting for the spawn model service to appear. It works with the laser equipped erratic, however:

```
roslaunch erratic_description erratic_laser_wg_world.launch
```

or:

```
roslaunch erratic_description erratic_laser_empty_world.launch
```

For the latter, you have to start the gui manually as it appears it was forgotten in the launch file.

Not sure why it doesn't work with the launch file in the original question, I suspect either
a) a subtle difference in launch files that I didn't catch or
b) a timing problem during gazebo startup which leads to the spawn model service not getting called.

/edit: As apparent from answer by arebgun, it was a) ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2012-10-15**:
Also the last time I used fuerte. The gazebo gui node is already into the launch file, in fact Gazebo GUI starts and it shows correctly the empty world, but not the robot.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-10-15**:
Sorry, apparently misread a part of your posting. Is there any output on the gazebo terminal? Can you spawn other models? (Plz comment here or edit your original post)